# LinkageError whilst trying to invoke CXF/SOAP webservice

Tags: java, soap, cxf, jboss6.x, linkageerror

I have a project (say myproject) in which I have hosted a CXF RESTful service and CXF WS/SOAP service, and running on JBoss (6.0.0.FINAL). The RESTful interface is used by all of our internal systems, and the SOAP interface is used by the third party systems (as a callback interface)

Following URLs are working fine.

- REST URL: `http://localhost:8080/myproject/internal/someOperation`   (`content-type: application/json` and POST body)
- SOAP WSDL: `http://localhost:8080/myproject/cbsoap?wsdl`

Now my problem is that actual SOAP calls are not successful. I use SOAPUI to try the SOAP calls but just to able to query the WSDL. I am getting the following error:-

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67)

root cause

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.cxf.jaxb.attachment.JAXBAttachmentUnmarshaller.getAttachmentAsDataHandler(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/cxf/jaxb/attachment/JAXBAttachmentUnmarshaller, and its superclass loader (instance of ), have different Class objects for the type r used in the signature
    org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBase.getAttachmentUnmarshaller(JAXBDataBase.java:78)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.createUnmarshaller(DataReaderImpl.java:123)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:156)
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:109)
    org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:209)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:191)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:114)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67)
```

Comment: This sounds really scary: `java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.cxf.jaxb.attachment.JAXBAttachmentUnmarshaller.getAttachmentAsDataHandler(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/cxf/jaxb/attachment/JAXBAttachmentUnmarshaller, and its superclass loader (instance of ), have different Class objects for the type r used in the signature`

Comment: I mean, different `Class` objects? Definitely sounds like class loader games gone wrong. (Not enough experience with debugging these things to help.)

Comment: My understanding is that the JAXBAttachmentUnmarshaller class is loaded twice (or already), and the getAttachmentAsDataHa‌​ndler method signatures are different. I am not sure if that makes sense. But need to get rid of one of them but don't know which one and how.

Comment: @DonalFellows  The issue here is that JBoss comes with Java 6+ and javax.activiation.DataHandler is actually included in standard Java 6.  When mixing it with different classloaders there is no way to be able to delegate the EAR/WAR to use it's own `javax.activation.DataHandler` since its a system level class.  Hence the LinkageError.  If it were a JAR included for JBoss the parent-last mechanism would work.

Comment: @VivekRagunathan The reason why it is probably not JAXBAttachmentUnmarshaller is because JAXBAttachmentUnmarshaller is not a system class (it is not included with the Java runtime) so no LinkageError should occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem but it is really weird.

1. I added cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws and cxf-bundle-rs as dependencies and mark some exclusions -> jetty-server, gernomino-servlet.
2. I had the beans.xml under WEB-INF folder but had to place it under src/main/resources. The beans.xml is expected to be under the classpath, instead of WEB-INF.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 6):

`LinkageError` is JBoss is generally caused by your app packaging its own copies of certain libraries that JBoss considers restricted. These are usually things in the `java.*` and `javax.*` packages.

Looking at your stack trace, I'd guess that the culprit is `javax.activation.DataHandler`. Check your app's bundled JAR files, make sure there's nothing like that in them. If there is, then remove it.

It may not be `javax.activation.DataHandler`, but may be something it in turn depends on.

Comment: These are the jars in my package lib (WEB-INF\lib). It does not have any javax.* but how do I find which one depends on that?

aopalliance-1.0.jar, asm-3.3.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, cxf-api-2.4.6.jar, cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.4.6.jar, cxf-common-utilities-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-core-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-transports-common-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-transports-http-2.4.6.jar, cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.4.6.jar, cxf-tools-common-2.4.6.jar
(continued....)

Comment: (continued....)
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.1.2.jar
jettison-1.3.1.jar
jetty-continuation-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-http-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-io-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-security-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-util-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.9.jar
neethi-3.0.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
(continued....)

Comment: (continued...)
spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlschema-core-2.0.1.jar

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: Open them all (with a zip tool) and have a look.

Comment: @VivekRagunathan skaffman is more then likely spot on with this.  There is almost certainly a third party library which is including the `javax.activation.DataHandler` class

Comment: I dont see that javax related jar in my lib. Not sure where it is pulling from.

Comment: You can search for classes in JAR files using a simple shell onliner in when in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder: `for x in 'ls' ; do unzip -l $x ; done | egrep 'jar|DataHandler` (just replace `'` with `backtick` around ls); if you are using maven for building and dependency management, you should exclude such libraries (in my case, it was pulled as a dependency of javax.mail) using `<exclusions>`: [maven doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)